# How to define a method that takes List<Base> and also List<Derived> in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have the following method

```
List<List<Animal>> animalsList = new List<List<Animal>>();

public void AddAnimal(List<Animal> animals)
{
   animalsList.Add(animals);
}
```

How can I use this method for `List<Dog>`?

I've tried

```
public void AddAnimal<T>(List<T> animals) where T: Animal
{
   animalsList.Add(animals);
}
```

That doesn't work either. Is there a way to define such a method?
I would use `IEnumerable<Animal>` but I need to reflect `.Add()`, `.Clear()` and such methods to internal lists without explicitly doing it.

Comment: It looks like `Animal` should be an interface.

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131583/serialization-list-of-different-object

Comment: @ozgur Because then if `Dog` implements the interface, you can easily do `animalsList.Add(listOfDogs);`

Comment: The latter example with an additional .Cast<T> Would fix it ?

Comment: @Sam that creates a new list. Then I lose the reference to those internal lists.

Comment: `IList<T>` is invariant in `T`. You can’t do what you want.

Comment: A list of dogs is not a list of animals; you can add a giraffe to a list of animals, but you can't add a giraffe to a list of dogs, so they must be incompatible types.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. That is: you have some problem, you have come up with a bad solution to that problem, and now you're asking about the bad solution. What's the real problem?

Comment: @EricLippert That sounds right=) My problem is this. I have a class GameEngine. It stores a list of **agents**. Outside the class, I have agent lists of different agent types. I use AddRange to add them to the game engine. So, whenever I remove an agent from one of those lists I want those agents to be removed from the engine's list. That's why I wanted to hold a list of lists of agents in engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for here is covariance, which C# doesn't support on generic classes, but does on generic interfaces. Moreover, [`IList<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/IList.cs,b19f71a84062554b) is not covariant, but [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/IEnumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0) is.

You could change the parameter to take in an `IEnumerable<Animal>` and then cast to a list within the method, which would then allow you to pass in collections of derived types of `Animal` to the method.

Comment: If I use IEnumerable<Animal> then I cannot force the api user to put a List<Animal> as a parameter. Am I right?

Comment: You couldn't enforce that at compile time, but could type check and throw an exception if they pass in a type that you don't want to work with. Kind of dirty, but it gets you closer to your intent.

Comment: @ozgur: If you look at your original code, you can see why `IList<T>` can't be covariant.  If you worked with `List<Dog>`, you could end up adding arbitrary Animals to your list of Dogs.  Bad things happen after that.  Arrays are covariant (for historical reasons dating back to pre-Generic times), and their covariance is the main type-safety leak in the Framework.  Simple collections (`IEnumerable<T>`) can be covariant because they can only be read, not changed.

Comment: @Flydog57 You are absolutely right. I think, because of what you said, what I want doesn't seem reasonable. But, in only a few cases being able to do this would be priceless.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        public void AddAnimal<T>(List<T> animals) where T : Animal
        {
            animalsList.Add(animals.Cast<Animal>().ToList());
        }
```